# Terminal starts with bash command

Tags: pantheon-terminal, bash

I am super new to linux environment and I am currently using Elementary OS. While trying to install Anaconda, it seems that I did something wrong. Now every time I open my terminal I am getting the following lines

bash: /home/username/.bashrc: line 171: syntax error near unexpected token `added'
bash: /home/username/.bashrc: line 171:`esac# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer'

I have no idea how to remove them. Any advice?

Comment: Did you try to remove said line (171) from ~/.bashrc?

Comment: @NirmalL I am still learning how to use the terminal, so  have no idea how to remove that

Answer (score 0):

Like @NirmalL commented, you should try to remove the line. You can either open the file with ElementaryOS Code as an editor or nano via terminal.

If you want to edit it in your terminal:

```
> nano ~/.bashrc
```

Edit the file and comment line 171 (# at the beginning of the line) as you should not remove something you don't understand. After that press "Ctrl+S" to save your changes and "Ctrl+X" to exit nano. Create a new Terminal tab to see if it is working.